# Class Variable NameError not defined python

Tags: python, class-variables

In this example, it's working 
hotels as a class variable no NameError

```
class Hotel():
    """""""""
    this is hotel class file
    """
    hotels = []
    def __init__(self,number,hotel_name,city,total_number,empty_rooms):
        self.number = number
        self.hotel_name = hotel_name
        self.city = city
        self.total_number = total_number
        self.empty_rooms = empty_rooms

        Hotel.hotels.append([number,hotel_name,city,total_number,empty_rooms])

    def list_hotels_in_city(self,city):
        for i in hotels:
            if city in i:
                print "In ",city,": ",i[1],"hotel, available rooms :",i[4]
```

In the following example its not working

```
from twilio.rest import Client


class Notifications():
    customers = []

    def __init__(self,customer_name,number,message):
        self.customer_name = customer_name
        self.number = number
        self.message = message
        Notifications.customers.append([customer_name,number,message])

    def send_text_message(self,customer_name):
        for i in customers:
            print "triggeredb"

inst = Notifications("ahmed","+00000000000","messagesample")
print "instance : ",inst.customers
inst.send_text_message("ahmed")
```

NameError: global name 'customers' is not defined

**Update**

for first example nothing called to show error 
but issue solved for second example Thanks  Tom Dalton , scharette and James

Comment: When you call `for i in customers:` `customers` is not in scope of that function.

Comment: Try `for i in self.customers:`

Comment: @TomDalton Thanks it's working now, but why in the first example I didn't use self.hotels and its working?

Comment: I don't know - have you defined a variable `hotels` at the module level?

Comment: It's not defined anywhere else, its same like both examples they are different files .

Comment: can you try it in your interpreter?

Comment: Solved question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, *When you call `for i in customers:`, `customers` is not in scope of that function.*

I just wanted to add also, that you use

```
 Notifications.customers.append([customer_name,number,message])
```

but you also declare

```
customers = []
```

Note that the former is a *class* variable and will share the variable among `Notifications` instances. The latter represent an *instance variable*. If your goal is to have a `customers` list for every specific object, you should use `self.customers`.

So basically,

**You want shared list between objects ?**

```
for i in Notifications.customers:
```

**You want specific list for every object ?**

```
for i in self.customers:
```

Comment: can you explain why its working in first example without Hotel.hotels or self.hotels

Comment: I prefer not to add this to my answer since it should not work. As @James said _when you ran your first example, you had a variable called hotels in your global (interpreter) scope._ which is probably the case.

Comment: actually you solved it but still I have a question how it's working in the first example but this will not affect the main requirement from my question.

Comment: can you try it in your interpreter?

Comment: @ahmedyounes, James did look his answer.

Comment: he said " If I copy paste your example into my interpreter" i want to make sure he did .

Answer (score 1):

I think it's very likely that when you ran your first example, you had a variable called hotels in your global (interpreter) scope. Thats why it's working. If I copy paste your example into my interpreter it fails with the same error message as your second code sample.

If your send_text_message function only accesses class variables (no instance variables) I would recommend making it a class method like this :

```
@classmethod
def send_text_message(cls, customer_name):
    for i in cls.customers:
        print "triggeredb"
```

That way you can access the class variables using the cls variable and won't have to repeat the class name in your function (which is nice, as if you change the class name - you won't have to go hunting through your code for repetitions).

Comment: Thanks for your notice but I'm trying to confirm that it will give an error in different global interpreter scope but it's not giving error !!

Comment: Check in locals() maybe? Or could you have it defined at the module level?

Comment: No it's not defined anywhere else just like the example I used in my question, it's really exhausting getting nervous :(

Comment: can you try it in your interpreter?

Comment: how can I remove or reset my interpreter, I restarted everything and still have this issue I even made a new class and for hotels its not giving error !!!